# Merge 2 tables in SQL and save into 1 new table

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge

If we have two or more tables with the same columns

Table 1

```
Structure, Name, Active
1,A,1
```

Table 2

```
Structure, Name, Active
2,B,0
```

We would like to combine these two tables and save it into a new one

New Table

```
Structure, Name, Active
1,A,1
2,B,0
```

Here is the code

```
CREATE TABLE Amide_actives_decoys
(
    Structure NVARCHAR(255),
    Name NVARCHAR(255),
    Active INT
)
GO

INSERT Amide_actives_decoys
FROM (
   SELECT * FROM Amide_decoys 
   UNION
   SELECT * FROM Amide_actives 
)
```

The following error message will show up

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.

The same thing if we use

```
SELECT * INTO Amide_actives_decoys
FROM (
   SELECT * FROM Amide_decoys 
   UNION
   SELECT * FROM Amide_actives 
)
```

Following this answer

[Joining a table onto itself in SQL and saving the result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18243507/joining-a-table-onto-itself-in-sql-and-saving-the-result)

The error message will be

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
>   Incorrect syntax near ';'.

Could any guru kindly offer some comments?  Thanks!

Comment: Plz refer this : http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/08/29/sql-server-three-methods-to-insert-multiple-rows-into-single-table-sql-in-sixty-seconds-024-video/

Answer (score 10):

This syntax works in different databases:

```
INSERT INTO Amide_actives_decoys(Structure, Name, Active)
   SELECT * FROM Amide_decoys 
   UNION
   SELECT * FROM Amide_actives;
```

> In this form of INSERT, the output of the subquery becomes the set of
>   input values for the INSERT.
>
> Note that the datatypes for the expressions in the SELECT statement
>   subquery must match the datatypes in the target table of the INSERT
>   statement.
>
> All of the rows returned by the subquery are inserted into the
>   Amide_actives_decoys table.
>
> If any one row fails the INSERT due to a constraint violation or
>   datatype conflict, the entire INSERT fails and no rows are inserted.
>
> Any valid subquery may be used within the INSERT statement.

Comment: +1 nice answer. Plz add explanation if possible that will be good :)

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to `UNION ALL` otherwise you may not capture all the data; depends on what data is in the table (duplicates etc).

```
INSERT INTO Amide_actives_decoys(Structure, Name, Active)
   SELECT * FROM Amide_decoys 
   UNION ALL
   SELECT * FROM Amide_actives;
```

Comment: Thanks Simon1979! Here we do need UNION ALL otherwise some data are missing!

Answer (score 2):

The General syntax is

```
INSERT INTO table2
SELECT * FROM table1;
```

you can SELECT INTO Statement in this Case

```
with cte as (select 1 col1 ,2 col2
union all
select 2,3) 
select * into #tabletest from cte

select *From #tabletest
```

Answer (score 2):

```
create table Amide_actives_decoys
as
select Structure, Name, Active from 
(
SELECT * FROM Amide_decoys 
UNION
SELECT * FROM Amide_actives 
)
;
```

Comment: It's best to explain your answers rather than just post code, as the OP may not entirely follow a code only answer.

Answer (score 1):

In both your answers, the issue is that you have not given an alias name for the table as a result.I think you missed an '`INTO`' in the `INSERT` statement as well.

Query 1:

```
CREATE TABLE Amide_actives_decoys
(
    Structure NVARCHAR(255),
    Name NVARCHAR(255),
    Active INT
)
GO

INSERT INTO Amide_actives_decoys
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT * FROM Amide_decoys 
        UNION
        SELECT * FROM Amide_actives 
        ) LU --LU is added.
```

For Query 1, the below also is correct

```
INSERT INTO Amide_actives_decoys
SELECT * FROM Amide_decoys 
UNION
SELECT * FROM Amide_actives
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT  * 
INTO    Amide_actives_decoys
FROM    (
        SELECT * FROM Amide_decoys 
        UNION
        SELECT * FROM Amide_actives 
        ) LU -- LU added
```

Comment: Good and detailed answer too! However, Here we do need UNION ALL otherwise some data are missing!

Answer (score 0):

SELECT
tab1.firstName,
tab1.lastName,
tab2.city,
tab2.state
FROM TABLE_1 tab1 LEFT JOIN TABLE_2 tab2
ON tab1.personId=tab2.personId

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO! Thank you for your contribution! In your future answers, please consider adding some explanations along with the code snippet. Also, you can use single or triple backticks to escape code snippets and even have code highlighting!